# How can I add this figure below in my latex file?

Tags: floats, packages

I have this image that I want to add in my latex file:
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{ amssymb }

    \pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I also want to label the figure.

Comment: You should use the `\includegraphics[options]{file.ext}` for insert that, but with the following structure: `\begin{figure}[htbp] \begin{center} \includegraphics[options]{file.ext}  \end{center} \caption[Short caption if needed]{Caption here}  \label{fig:figurename} \end{figure}`. Please read [How to import graphics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) for understand it better.

Comment: @Aradnix Generally it's best to leave out the extension of the graphics file, and use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment ([Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651))).

Comment: @Aradnix: One should use `\centering` rather than the `center` environment, which adds spurious vertical spacing.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? What else do you need self-solving question?

Comment: @percusse It is downvoted, because imho @user36829 did not even try to resolve it by him/herself, see [the rules](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The `\includegraphics` command is the very basic one -- so this was the main reason. Another minor reason is that the source code provided is useless for resolving this kind of question, because there are only listed packages and newcommands.

Comment: @VáclavPavlík I don't want to get into that rules debate. We don't have any rules here. See meta.TeX.SE for a lot of related discussion. Research required is a SO thing. We don't have it here. In summary, SO habits don't apply. We only have guidelines.

Comment: @percusse I do not want to have any dispute either and this is certainly not the place to have it. I think it is clear why I voted down and I can support it by many arguments. So please let me have my opinion.

Comment: @VáclavPavlík Bring it up in chat you'll be informed better by others too. It's not just your opinion but a community etiquette.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right, it was my mistake to copy and paste without changing the snippet of Sublime Text 2 I used.

Comment: @Bernard It's true but many snippets that are used to compose figures and even some books recommend using the `center` environment, I use `centering` when I have many figures in a document, I understand that consumes less memory.

Comment: @ Aradnix: I see. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{tikz}` to your preamble.

Then where you want your figure insert the following code.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%axis
\draw (12,0) -- (0,0)--(0,10);
% Blue lines
\draw[blue] (0,9)node[left]{\color{black}20} -- (11,0)node[below]{\color{   black}12}node[near end,right]{\color{black}$MC_2$};
\draw[blue] (0,9) -- (9,0)node[below]{\color{black}10}node[near end,left]{  \color{black}$MC_1$};
% Red lines
\draw[red] (0,1) -- (5,10)node[near end,right]{\color{black}$MB_1$};
\draw[red] (0,0.5) -- (8,10)node[near end,right]{\color{black}$MB_2$};
% Dotted lines
\draw[dotted,thick] (2.85,0)node[below]{$I^*$} -- (2.85,6.1)--(0,6.1)node[  left]{$U(I^*)$};
\draw[dotted,thick] (4.25,0)node[below]{$I$} -- (4.25,5.53)--(0,5.53)node[  left]{$U(I)$};
\draw (0,0)node[below]{0}node[left]{0};
\end{tikzpicture}
%Figure caption
\caption{Demo of TikZ Figure}
\end{figure}
```

To produce the graf below

[image: Graf]

Comment: Sweet! But is this for drawing the actual graph without loading it from a file? I want to load some graphs in my latex.

Comment: @user36829 This is a very basic question. Try to read this [article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics).